# Where are civicrm profile custom fields stored in the DB?

Tags: civicontribute, wordpress

I have a contribution form with profile with custom fields, I want to know where the custom fields data is stored in the DB for every new contact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from [CiviCRM data architecture](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+data+architecture?desktop=true):

> When you add custom data to a CiviCRM object, you first create a
>   custom data group and then add custom data fields. At the database
>   layer, what you are doing is creating a new table for the custom data
>   group and adding columns for the fields.

If you crate a custom data group called ***My Custom Data*** with a field ***Name***, Civi will create a new table in your database like this: `civicrm_value_my_custom_data_1`, **1** being the group id. The table has an id column (primary key) an entity_id column (fk to the entity, ie. contact_id, contribution_id, etc), and one column per each field you have created, in this case would be `name_1`.

Field ***Name*** for contact_id 50 in sql would be: 
`select name_1 from civicrm_value_my_custom_data_1 where entity_id=50;`

Hope is clear.